# What are the common mistakes when Vue.js routing is not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I've been working on an e-commerce like page as the attached images, and now I'm trying to do the basically same thing using vue-router.

[image: e-commerce]
[image: cart]

In the previous version (without vue-routing) I could navigate through different pages, for example from the Main page to Cart page, shown as the attached images, but when I tried to do the same with vue-routing I couldn't jump to the cart page. Besides just clicking the "Cart" tab, I also tried adding

```
/#/cart
```

at the end of the URL by directly typing it in, but that didn't work either.

At this moment I'm following a series of video lectures, so I'm referring to the sample code provided. So if it were caused by some typing errors, there would be some error messages like

```
"undefined XXX"
"cannnot find XXX"
etc
```

displayed on the console.

But there is no error message displayed on console, so it's hard to identify where to start to look for the cause of this bug.

I found another question about vue-routing on Stack Overflow, but the cause of the error for that particular case was that he / she was trying to directly reference HTML files in the route configuration, which I don't think has something to do with my problem, so I think I need to ask my own question.

The below are some parts of the code for this e-commerce like practice app.

***main.js***

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import ProductList from './ProductList.vue';
import Cart from './Cart.vue';

Vue.filter('currency', function(value){
  let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD',
      minimumFranctionDigits: 0
  });

  return formatter.format(value);
});

export const eventBus = new Vue();

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '', component: ProductList },
    { path: '/cart', component: Cart}
  ],
  mode: 'history'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router: router
})
```

***App.vue (only template part)***

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">E-commerce Inc.</a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <div class="stats">{{ cart.items.length }} 
                          <template v-if="cart.items.length == 1">item</template><template v-else>items</template>in cart, totalling {{ cartTotal | currency }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <router-view :cart="cart"></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

Can it be something wrong with the content of the code, or is it possible that I didn't install something vital for vue-routing? So far I have at least installed vue-router, and also enabled and registered it.

Comment: I guess your vue router mode:history is  activated gives an error. if you activate the mode:'history' your url should be not have "/#/".

Comment: I tried the url without /#/ as you suggested, and that worked perfectly fine! As I was still not familiar with how vue-routing works, I ended up somehow mixing up the code for URL with /#/ and the one without it... I appreciate your help anyway!

Comment: try to read vue-router documentation https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode to get more details whats going on using vue-router. happy coding!